# How to show a pop up UIViewController with a UICollectionView in it in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

The UIViewController with UICollectionView works fine if I launch it from storyboard. However, when I try to launch it like this:

```
let imagePicker = imagePickerControllerViewController()
imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

It crashes on line:

```
collectionView.dataSource = self
```

The question is, how to show a UIViewController (that has a UICollectionView) modally properly?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: This means that collectionView.dataSource = self is being called before either collectionView or data source is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced :

```
let imagePicker = imagePickerControllerViewController()
```

With:

```
let imagePicker = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("imagePicker") as! imagePickerControllerViewController
```